# How to handle Day Light Saving time in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, timezone

In our Marketing Cloud emails we send emails which contain time slots for Appointments to customers.

The data is stored in UTC time in Sales Cloud, and then copied over to Marketing Cloud Data Extensions in the same timezone (using MC connector). However the customers are based in the UK so they can be GMT or BST (+ 1 hour), how can we display the correct time without having to manually add/remove offsets every 6 months when the timezeone changes?

Edit:

This is my current AMPScript

```
set @AppointmentDate = "4/14/2019 7:15:00 AM"
set @AppointmentDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(@AppointmentDate)
set @formatDate = FormatDate(@AppointmentDate, "YY/MM/DD","", "en-GB")
set @formatTime = Format(@AppointmentDate, "h:mmtt")

Outputline(Concat(@formatDate, " ", @formatTime))
```

The outputs `19/04/14 2:15PM`

The MC Account is set to `GMT*`, the * indicates DST is being observed so its (+1 hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your account Time Zone is set to correct UK region, you can use [SystemDateToLocalDate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm)

Comment: Please have a look at my updated question, it was my understanding dates are stored in UTC time, my account MC account timezone is set to `GMT *`. This should have only added 1 hour to the time, its +7 hours instead.